# Retrieving data from sql in java class

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hashmap

```
SELECT REQUEST_ID,LOGIN_USER,PRICE,STATUS from TABLE ORDER BY REQUEST_ID DESC
```

JAVA CODE:

```
public class DBConnection {
    public HashMap<Object, List<Dashboard>>  getStoreResult() {
        ArrayList<Dashboard> dashRec=new ArrayList<Dashboard>();
        HashMap<Object, List<Dashboard>> map = new HashMap<>();
        try{
            Class.forName("");
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("");
            Statement st=con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("SELECT REQUEST_ID,LOGIN_USER,PRICE,STATUS from TABLE ORDER BY REQUEST_ID DESC ");
            while (rs.next()) {
                }
             return map;
```

I am using sql query to retrieve data in hashmap in java.The hashmap has key as object which consists of reqid,name,lowest status of a set.Here set refers to all rows of a unique id.For instance,reqid 123 has 7 rows ,so lowest status no is 1.In hashmap value,I have arraylist which has all rows as objects of a particuler reqid.When I execute the query in sql, the results are as my changes in query.I mean changes take place in Order by reqid desc or Order by reqid asc.But when I do the same in java class the results for all three remains same i.e. `Order by reqid desc or Order by reqid asc or Order by reqid`.What can be the cause of the error?

[image: SQL DB]

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: Is that sample table data or the expected result? BTW, most people here want formatted text, not images.

Comment: @jarlh I am using Oracle.Its sample table data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure try to this way LinkedHashMap takes the order.

```
LinkedHashMap<Object, List<Dashboard>> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
```